# Python convert a list of .txt to .xls

Tags: python, xls, xlwt

I found this useful script to convert a list of .txt files to xls files. I'm still a Python newbie and having some trouble with fixing the error in my script. The script used is below:

```
mypath = "I give my path here"

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False        

import xlwt
import xlrd

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'  

for textfile in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split(';'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if is_number(value):
                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

The script produces output files for the first 10 files which are all less than 1MB. The script fails en produces the following error message for a file that is ~42MB:

```
 File
 "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py",
 line 37, in __init__
     raise ValueError("row index was %r, not allowed by .xls format" % rowx)
 ValueError: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format
```

Would anyone be able to assist me with the error?

Comment: Try with `.xlsx` format. `.xls` only allows a max row index of 65536 where as `.xlsx` (Excel 2007 onwards) allows 1048576 rows.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the input has more than 65535 rows?

Comment: I would ideally want it to still write the output to a single file but if it exceeds the row count of 1048576 in xlsx then I'll split it into multiple files.

Comment: the xlwt module was written for use with .xls. How would I go about changing the output to be in a .xlsx format? If I change the last line of the code to replace the .txt to .xlsx it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You get the error message because the file format `.xls` only allows 65536 rows (indexing starts at 0).

You should consider using either the `.xlsx` format or if you need the backwards compatibility either use `.xlsx` as a "fallback" format if the row count exceeds 65536, or split the output into multiple files.